# Compiling libavcodec with emscripten (with hardware acceleration)

Tags: ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration, libavcodec

I am trying to compile libavcodec library with emscripten to generate a wasm to be used in a web project. It works, but I wanted to enable hardware acceleration (at least for OSX) but I cannot make it working.
I am using this configuration:

--cc=emcc \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --target-os=none \
    --arch=x86 \
    --disable-runtime-cpudetect \
        --disable-asm \
    --disable-stripping \
        \
        --disable-bzlib \
    --disable-iconv \
    --disable-libxcb \
    --disable-lzma \
    --disable-sdl \
    --disable-securetransport \
    --disable-xlib \
    --disable-zlib \
        --disable-network \
    --disable-d3d11va \
    --disable-dxva2 \
    \
        --disable-all \
        --disable-everything \
        --enable-ffmpeg \
        --enable-avcodec \
        --enable-avformat \
    --enable-avutil \
    --enable-avfilter \
    --enable-swresample \
    --enable-swscale \
    --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-decoder=hevc \
    --enable-encoder=mjpeg \
    --enable-vda \
    --enable-hwaccel=h264_vda \
    --enable-vaapi \
        --enable-shared

but the result is: no hwaccels enabled. Is there something I am missing in the configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Incompatible requirements. WASM does not (and can not) support vaapi, h264_vda or anything else that requires low level kernel/driver integration.